# Enlarge icons on Status Bar for Galaxy S5 Active

Tags: notification-bar, samsung-galaxy-s-5

Is there a way to enlarge the icons in the status bar on the Galaxy S5 Active (e.g., voicemail notification, battery charge status, e-mail notification, etc.)?

Comment: Without root, none that I know of. Even rooted it can be tricky if the ROM/framework/software doesn't support it.

Comment: I was just about to ask the same, but for **S5 mini**. My wife uses reading glasses, but on her old phone with smaller screen, **Galaxy Ace**, she can read *without glasses* the percentage of battery charge that the battery widget app displays in the notification bar. The annoying thing is that the bottom of the notification bar of **S5 mini** has excessive blank space!